# What is the difference between AppCenter OS updates and apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: updates, system, appcenter

AppCenter operating system update shows 55MB to be downloaded but doing

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

shows 125MB to be downloaded. Is it because dist-upgrade updates dependencies?

TDLR: What is the fundamental difference between apt-get and AppCenter OS updates?

Comment: Maybe there is none?